# Block php files except in one directory

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to block all calls to php files in a specific folder and subfolders except for one specific folder and its subfolders.

I've tried a number of different regex permutations and I can get the regex to match properly, it's implementing in htaccess where I have a problem.

This is the htaccess file as it is now:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:php)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

and this is the regex expression that matches properly outside of htaccess:

```
^(?!.*(thedirectory)).*(?i:php)$
```

When I check that regex against index.php it matches. When I check against /thedirectory/index.php it does not match. When I check against /someotherdirectory/style.css it does not match.

How I'd like it to work is:

```
domain.com/folder/index.php -> 404 Error
domain.com/folder/thedirectory/index.php -> resolves
domain.com/folder/someotherdirectory/index.php -> 404 Error
domain.com/folder/someotherdirectory/afunction.php -> 404 Error
domain.com/folder/someotherdirectory/style.css -> resolves
```

Comment: Does this need to work on both Apache 2.2 and 2.4?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a lot more straightforward than I thought it would be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*(thedirectory)).*(?i:php)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule "(.*)" /404.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper. If (for whatever reason) mod_rewrite is not available then the user will get unrestricted access (the directives are not executed). Without the wrapper, the user gets a 500 error - content is secure. Only if the directives are _optional_ should you be using an `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: Note that your current `RewriteRule` _rewrites_ the request to `/404.php`. It is then up to your PHP script to return the 404 HTTP status. You could instead trigger the Apache error document (via an internal subrequest): `RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]`. Or trigger a 403 Forbidden (like the mod_authz... directives) with the `F` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` sections match just the filename, not the directory path. So attempting to do so will naturally fail.

An alternative approach is to simply create an additional `.htaccess` file in the directory you want to allow access, which will override the parent:

```
Require all granted
```